# How to align rows in matplotlib legend with 2 columns

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an issue where some mathtext formatting is making some labels take up more vertical space than others, which causes them to not line up when placed in two columns in the legend. This is particularly important because the rows are also used to indicate related data.

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mathtext as mathtext
mpl.rc("font", family="Times New Roman",weight='normal')
plt.rcParams.update({'mathtext.default':  'regular' })
plt.plot(1,1, label='A')
plt.plot(2,2, label='B')
plt.plot(3,3, label='C')
plt.plot(4,4,label='$A_{x}^{y}$')
plt.plot(5,5,label='$B_{x}^{y}$')
plt.plot(6,6,label='$C_{x}^{y}$')
plt.legend(fontsize='xx-large', ncol=2)
plt.show()
```

This generates a figure like so:
[image]

For a while, I was able to "fake it" a bit by adding some empty subscripts and superscripts, however this only works when the plot is exported to pdf. It does not appear to work when exporting to png. How can I spread out the first column of labels so that they line up with the second column?

Comment: Have you tried changing your matplotlib backend? Some of them export differently than others.

Comment: The only thing I've ever done with backends is to import PdfPages for multi-page pdfs. As far as I know, I'm using AGG to render the png as I believe that's the default. I could perhaps try Cairo but I have a set of 50-100 unique plots that also may change so I'm kind of looking for a more sand-boxed approach here.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could set the `handleheight` keyword argument to a number which is just large enough that the height of the handle is larger than the space taken by the font. This makes the text appear aligned. Doing so may require to set the `labelspacing` to a small number, in order not to make the legend appear too big.

```
plt.legend(fontsize='xx-large', ncol=2,handleheight=2.4, labelspacing=0.05)
```

[image]

The drawback of this method, as can be seen in the picture, is that the lines shift upwards compared to the text's baseline. It would probably depent on the usage case if this is acceptable or not.

In case it is not, one needs to dig a little deeper. The following subclasses `HandlerLine2D` (which is the Handler for Lines) in order to set a slightly different position to the lines. Depending on the total legend size, font size etc. one would need to adapt the number `xx` in the `SymHandler` class.

```
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D
import matplotlib.lines

class SymHandler(HandlerLine2D):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        xx= 0.6*height
        return super(SymHandler, self).create_artists(legend, orig_handle,xdescent, xx, width, height, fontsize, trans)

leg = plt.legend(handler_map={matplotlib.lines.Line2D: SymHandler()}, 
            fontsize='xx-large', ncol=2,handleheight=2.4, labelspacing=0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic. Does updating the HandlerLine2D like this affect anything beyond the scope of this legend? I have generally tried to avoid inheritance so I am not familiar with this type of thing. Are the arguments in the function create_artists inherited and that's why you don't need to specify them? The xx factor is where the bottom of the line begins, normalized to the handleheight?